# Reading and setting views when layout is associated with fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Hi I am making an android app to where I have Tabs implemented through fragments But I cannot figure out how to read and set views inside the fragments as fragments does not allow it to be but the layout is associated with those fragments.Also I have AsyncTask with I want to execute on onChangeListener for switch in the layout of that fragment. am new to android with no prior knowledge. here is how created Tabs

```js
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Devices"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("°C & H%"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Video"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Device Control"
        android:id="@+id/Heading"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#d009b958"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:backgroundTint="#380ac161" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toggle Switch for Your Required Function"
        android:id="@+id/top_textview"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Heading"
        android:layout_marginStart="55sp"/>



    <Switch
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Light"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_textview"
        android:textColor="#d009b958"
        android:layout_marginStart="60sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Curent Status"
        android:id="@+id/text_status_led"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_marginStart="85sp"/>

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fan"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/switch2"
        android:textOn="ON"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/switch1"
        android:textColor="#d009b958"
        android:layout_marginStart="60sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Curent Status"
        android:id="@+id/text_status_fan"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/switch2"
        android:layout_marginStart="85sp"/>

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Door"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/switch3"
        android:textOn="ON"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/switch2"
        android:layout_marginStart="60sp"
        android:textColor="#d009b958"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Curent Status"
        android:id="@+id/text_status_door"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/switch3"
        android:layout_marginStart="85sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/switch3"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Temaperature :"
        android:textColor="#d009b958"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/text_temperature"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_status_door"
        android:layout_marginStart="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00 °C"
        android:textColor="#000001"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_temperature"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25sp"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:id="@+id/text_value_temperature"

        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use this example : https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fragments are used to decouple views from activities.**

Like how you extend an Activity to create your custom Activity, you will have to extend Fragment to create a custom fragment(assuming you know what an Activity is).

Refer to the fragment lifecycle below.

[image: Fragment lifecycle]

The

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

is where you will inflate your custom view in using the inflater object.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, parent, false);
```

The third argument has to be false **always**. It denotes if the view is to be attached to be parent, which will happen automatically and if you set to **true**, while throw an exception.
Now you have the `View` object where you can work on like how you would in your Activity and **return this view** from the onCreateView method.

In the `ViewPager` you set an adapter and that should be a custom adapter to supply your fragments (in the `getItem(int position)` method). There is no need to use AsyncTask at all!

[This is a good place](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/animation/screen-slide.html) to start for ViewPagers and understand fragments. Tabs are just an icing over what you have already:)

Comment: I did try but apparently I am not experienced enough on Stack. :)

Comment: @ShahrozeTariq I would suggest to break what you want to do in small tasks and approach one problem at a time